Can Polynomials Approximate a Bounded Function on the Entire Real Line?
According to the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, a polynomial can approximate a continuous function on a closed interval.
I agree that, a polynomial cannot approximate a target function which is unbounded on an open interval, because the polynomial itself would be bounded on that interval, while the target function is not.
This is discussed in detail here.
My question: Can a polynomial approximate a function that is bounded on the entire real line, $(-\infty, +\infty)$?
For example, consider the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution $\Phi$, which is upper bounded by $1$ and lower bounded by $1$ on the entire real line.
Can that be approximated by a polynomial?

A bona fide (i.e. finite) polynomial cannot be bounded on the entire real line, no. Such a function would necessarily tend to infinity. If you allow power series, however, then yes. Trigonometric functions, for example, can be expressed as "infinite" polynomials.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded, and let $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be any non-constant polynomial function. We show that
$$\lVert f-p\rVert_\infty=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\lvert f(x)-p(x)\rvert=\infty.$$
Suppose for a contradiction that
$$\lVert f-p\rVert_\infty=c<\infty.$$
Set
$$s=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\lvert f(x)\rvert.$$
As $p$ is unbounded we can find some $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\lvert p(\xi)\rvert>s+c.$$
But then
$$c\geq \lvert f(\xi)-p(\xi)\rvert\geq\lvert p(\xi)\rvert-\lvert f(\xi)\rvert>\underbrace{s-\lvert f(\xi)\rvert}_{\geq0}+c\geq c.$$
In particular $c>c$, which is a contradiction.

Polynomial $P(x)=\sum_0^n C_a x^a$ is itself unbounded :
It will tend to $\pm \infty$ when $x$ tending to $\pm \infty$ , depending on (A) Sign of $C_n$ [ that is : Positive / Negative ] (B) Parity of $n$ ( that is : $n \bmod 2$ )
Hence the Answer is NO
Exception :
$P(x)=C_0$ is trivially bounded
